# Open all again after restarting the pc on Windows

Tags: windows

I've been using windows desktops a lot to divide my work/leisure sections (windows+tab).
However, when I restart the pc, everything closes.

Would there be a way or some program to open everything again with one click? (like save everything I was using before and open everything with one click)

Note: The windows I say are multiple desktops

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not natively support this. However, given that Hybrid shutdown is active by default, the following logic is currently in effect:

A shutdown closes all programs and then put windows in hibernation, reducing the startup time.

Given that hibernation is already being used, your best opion here is to hibernate your windows when you are done for the day. The next day, your programs are not only open, but they are open at the exact location you had them open with the exact state.

Of course, this means that every once in a while, you do want to restart your computer and then you have to launch all your programs again, but that's really the best way to do it.

You can place shortcuts to all the programs you definitely use in `shell:startup` so they start up as your computer restarts.

Comment: I'm surprised Windows hasn't had a go at implementing this feature yet. It's been standard in macOS for over a decade.

Comment: @Tetsujin there is an option to reopen programs at reboot when doing windows update, but you can't force it for a shutdown and only with windows updates. Also, does not work with every program for some reason. Yes, its weird.

Comment: @LPChip Suspending is really the best way, however, sometimes I leave my notebook using something like teamviewer or anydesk, and when I'm not at home and the light goes out the notebook turns off. This sucks having to open everything again!

Comment: Even on a mac, if it loses power, the reboot is always clean and won't remember what programs were running previously. That cannot be changed. But you can set in power settings to automatically hibernate on battery after x minutes, which should stop your problem.

Comment: @LPChip - I live in an area where power cuts are a once-in-a-decade experience, so it's not really something I ever have to deal with. One you re-launch each app, though, they will come back up just as they were last time you saw them [with exceptions, Adobe & Microsoft being the worst culprits. Though each has an attempt at their own auto-recover, it's not as good as Apple's own]

Comment: @Tetsujin same for me, but a powercut will also happen if you set your power options to never hibernate, and you don't have your laptop plugged into the mains, and you then forget to turn it off, which is what OP could be doing.

Comment: @LPChip - agreed… but as I don't own a laptop at all, for me this is another non-issue ;)) idk what a MacBook does if it's asleep & runs out of power - you'd have to assume a controlled shutdown would be the most sensible course of action, but I honestly don't know.